# Column cannot be null - procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure in `MySQL` that `insert` `week`s (for current year) to my `week` table. But there is a problem because after first row is added for the next one I get an error: `number column cannot be null`. I am new to `MySQL` so I will appreciate any help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE generateWeeks()
BEGIN
    SET @currentYear = YEAR(CURDATE());
    SET @nextYear = @currentYear + 1;

    SET @startOfCurrentWeek = CURDATE();

    WHILE(@currentYear < @nextYear) DO
        SET @endOfCurrentWeek = DATE_ADD(@startOfCurrentWeek , INTERVAL 7 DAY);
        SET @weekNumber = WEEK(@startOfCurrentWeek, 3) -
            WEEK(@startOfCurrentWeek - INTERVAL DAY(@startOfCurrentWeek)-1 DAY, 3) + 1;
        INSERT INTO `week` (`number`, `start_date`, `end_date`)
        VALUES (@weekNumber, @startOfCurrentWeek, @endOfCurrentWeek);
        SET @startOfCurrentWeek = @endOfCurrentWeek + 1;
        SET @currentYear = YEAR(@endOfCurrentWeek);
     END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

EDITED:
Table Creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `week` (
  `id`          INT(11)      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `number`      INT(11)      NOT NULL,
  `start_date`  DATE         NOT NULL,
  `end_date`    DATE         NOT NULL
)
```

Why for first `while` iteration everything is ok (rows is added), but in the next one I get `null` value in `@weekNumber` variable ?

Comment: Well, the error message says it and you can see it in your create table statement. The number column doesn't allow null values, yet you try to insert a null value (or you don't insert anything into this column). Simple as that. Check the values of your variables.

Comment: But I would like to provide week number for every week (during insert), so how can I change procedure in order to avoid `null` value in `@weekNumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
SET @startOfCurrentWeek = @endOfCurrentWeek + 1;
```

will convert the variable into a integer. Use date_add instead.

Also, instead of using user-defined variables (@endOfCurrentWeek) you better use local variabled (declare v_endOfCurrentWeek date).

Comment: is `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` ok ?

Comment: Yes, that is ok as well